# ASP.NET Core 3: InvalidOperationException: No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is an exception after I migrate my project to .NET Core 3.1.

The exception occurs in the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();    // in this line
});
```

The exception itself is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Payoneer.WorkingCapital.MyOffering.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__36_1(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in C:\Payoneer\working-capital-my-offering-core\WebApi\Startup.cs:line 823
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Payoneer.WorkingCapital.MyOffering.WebApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Payoneer\working-capital-my-offering-core\WebApi\Startup.cs:line 821
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

This was not happened when the project was with .NET Core 2.1.

how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share all your Startup.cs, please?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Startup.cs class. For MapController, first of all you must register the "Controllers Servcie" in **ConfigureService** method and use endpoints middleware in **Configuration** method.

In **ConfigureService** method:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

In **Configuration** method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

- More about Dependency Injection in .NET Core 3.1 - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- More about Middleware in .NET Core 3.1 - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was some old Nuget package that does not support .NET Core 3.1.
After removing it, everything starts to work as expected.
The problem package was "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples".